# How to design textboxes right side of the page mvc razor

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to place my Login (Username, Password) in right side of the page. I am new to razor. I need help.I don't get any idea, if jquery is helpful or not. Anyone give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove from the CSS

```
clear:right
```

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/5tMM7/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific you need to do for a razor implementation.  You can use CSS applied to your inputs and place them wherever you need:

For example:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="user"/>
    <input type="text"  class="password"/>
    <input type="button" value="I'm on the left" />
</div>
```

With CSS of:

```
input.user, input.password
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

Here is a fiddle that demos it: http://jsfiddle.net/5tMM7/